# How to use word2vec with keras CNN (2D) to do text classification?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, gensim, word2vec

There is Convolution1D example https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py without word2vec.

Currently, I am using gensim to train word2vec model.

I want to use word2vec and keras cnn(2D not 1D) to do document classifacation(Chinese Text). I learned the basic flow of text classification in cnn and want to do a test.

### For example(the steps I imagine):

1. Use a good Cinese Tokenized Text Set to train word2vec model

   ```
   model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(new_sentences, workers=10, size=200, min_count=2)
   ```
2. Tokenize my sentences dataset to words lists dataset(the longest sentence has over 8000 words, shortest is less 50)

   ```
   1     ['你们', '好', '今天', '天气', '真', '好']
   2     ['嗯', '对的']
   ...
   9999  ['好', '就', '这样']
   ```
3. Use a method to transform words lists dataset to word2vec dataset

   transform every word in every sencence to a vec by trained model.

   ```
   1     [[word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200]]
   2     [[word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200]]
   ...
   9999  [[word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200]]
   ```
4. Pad  word2vec dataset (with size=200 zero array)

   ```
   1     [[word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200]]
   2     [[word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200]]
   ....
   9999  [[word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200]]
   ```
5. go to the  CNN (using Convolution2D)

---

I search for a long time, but can't find any way to do the step 3 ( after step 3,  the parameter and layers setting in step 5 is hard to understand too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Transforming a single sentence to a 2D vector**

Assuming you have a list of words and a model you can do:

```
import numpy as np
sentence_vec = None
for word in sentence:
    word_vec = np.expand_dims(model[word], axis=0)
    if sentence_vec is None:
        sentence_vec = word_vec
    else:
        sentence_vec = np.concatenate((sentence_vec, word_vec), axis=0)
```

As for step 5 - it would be helpful if you listed what you are having trouble with. Basically you only need to do is change both 1D operations (Convolution1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D) to their 2D counter-parts .

Comment: Thanks, haven't thought it was so simple that just `model[word]` ! I had looked all the method of `gensim.models.Word2Vec` and didn't find something named like `transform`, which even make me thought if I am choose wrong lib... About the `step 5`, I just have no idea about how many layers  it need  , each layer use which dropout or not ? what activation function? etc.. this step is very hard to understand..

Comment: Without prior experience with a specific problem it is pretty hard to guess what architecture would work best. I'd suggest looking for articles that are doing similar stuff and try the stuff that they are doing. This would include the 1D example you linked but updated for 2D, other works that do CNN on text (CharCNN and others).

It is mostly a matter of trial and error.

Comment: I have posted a question about how to use `Convolution2D` , would you mind to have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798359/how-to-set-proper-arguments-to-build-keras-convolution2d-nn-model-text-classifi