# How to set proper arguments to build keras Convolution2D NN model [Text Classification]?

Tags: neural-network, classification, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use 2D CNN to do text classification on Chinese Article and have trouble on setting arguments of keras `Convolution2D`. I know the basic flow of `Convolution2D` to cope with image, but stuck by using my dataset with keras.

### Input data

```
My data is 9800 Chinese Article, max sentence length is 6810，with 200 word2vec size.
So the input shape is `(9800, 1, 6810, 200)`
```

#### Code for building model

```
MAX_FEATURES = 6810

# I just randomly pick one filter, seems this is the problem?
nb_filter = 128

input_shape = (1, 6810, 200)

# each word is 200 (word2vec size)
embedding_size = 200 

# 3 word length
n_gram = 3 

# so stride here is embedding_size*n_gram

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter, n_gram, embedding_size, border_mode='valid', input_shape=input_shape))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(100, 1), border_mode='valid'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(hidden_dims))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


# X is (9800, 1, 6810, 200)

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32,
              nb_epoch=5,
              validation_split=0.1)
```

**Question 1**. I have problem to set `Convolution2D` arguments. My reseach is below,

The official docs do not contain an exmaple for 2D CNN text classifacation(though has 1D CNN).

`Convolution2D` defination is here https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/:

```
keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution2D(nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col, init='glorot_uniform', activation=None, weights=None, border_mode='valid', subsample=(1, 1), dim_ordering='default', W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None, bias=True)
```

> nb_filter: Number of convolution filters to use.
>     nb_row: Number of rows in the convolution kernel. 
>     nb_col: Number of columns in the convolution kernel. 
>     border_mode: 'valid', 'same' or 'full'. ('full' requires the Theano backend.)

Some research about the arguments:

- This issue https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/233 is about 2D CNN for text classification, I read all comments and pick:

  (1) https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/233#issuecomment-117427013

  ```
  model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter=N_FILTERS, stack_size=1, nb_row=FIELD_SIZE,
                      nb_col=1, subsample=(STRIDE, 1)))
  ```

  (2) https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/233#issuecomment-117700913

  ```
  sequential.add(Convolution2D(nb_feature_maps, 1, n_gram, embedding_size))
  ```

  But it seems has some diference to current keras version, also the arguments naming by different people are in a mess (I hope keras has an easy understandable argument expanation).
- Another comment I see about current api:

  https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1665#issuecomment-181181000

  > The current API is as below:
  >
  > ```
  >     keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution2D(nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col, init='glorot_uniform', activation='linear', weights=None, border_mode='valid', subsample=(1, 1), dim_ordering='th', W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None)
  > ```
  >
  > So (36,1,7,7) seems the reason, the correct arguments would be (36,7,7,...).

By above research, on my understanding of convolution, `Convolution2D` create a (nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col) filter , by sliding a stride to get one filter result, recurse sliding, finally combine the result into array with shape (1, one_sample_article_length[6810] / nb_filter), and go to the next layer, is that right? Is my code below set `nb_row` and `nb_col` correct ?

**Question 2**. What is the proper MaxPooling2D arguments?  (for my dateset or for commonm, either is OK)

I refer this issue https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/233#issuecomment-117427013 to set the argument, there are two kinds:

- `MaxPooling2D(poolsize=(((nb_features - FIELD_SIZE) / STRIDE) + 1, 1))`
- `MaxPooling2D(poolsize=(maxlen - n_gram + 1, 1))`

I have no idea why they calculate `MaxPooling2D` argument like that.

**Question 3**. Any recommendation for `batch_size` and `nb_epoch` to do such text classification? I have no idea at all.

Comment: I think you should break up this one question into several, separate questions. Six questions in one is a bit much.

Comment: @nemo No problem, I would separate it now.

Comment: @nemo Any suggestion to separeate the last three problems? I don't know much , but they seems relate to each other.

Comment: @Mithril Yes, they are related to each other, of course.  You can keep them somewhat together by using tags effectively.  You can also re-submit the background info for each of the 3 (6??) questions.  You can also provide links to the other questions.  (E.g., if you create 3 questions, then each of the 3 questions can have 2 links to the other 2.)  HTH!

Comment: @Mithril Also, I wanted to help with an answer, but I'm not sure how you're using the CNN.  Are you doing something similar [to this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5882)? Do you already have the word vectors?  (Seems like you do.)  Can you explain the dimensions in your input vector `(9800, 1, 6810, 200)`?  I presume `9800` is the # of samples, `200` is the number of dimensions in the word vector, `6810` seems to be the sentence length (!!), and what is `1`?  In short, what are the non-Keras-related issues?  How do you want to make the model?